# Ethernet lights not on when cable connected and connection not working

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager, ethernet, interface

I have two OSs and the Ethernet lights on my computer don't turn on when the cable connected and I cannot connect to the internet. This is not a hardware problem, since my second OS connects to internet easily.

The output of `lspci` is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
23:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
23:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
23:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller (rev 30)
24:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
25:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

Output of `lshw -C network`:

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:24:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 74:de:2b:02:0b:da
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.18.2-031802-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:19 memory:d4600000-d460ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: 10:1f:74:e3:50:5a
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:29 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d4404000-d4404fff memory:d4400000-d4403fff
```

Output of `ifup eth0`:

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/10:1f:74:e3:50:5a
Sending on   LPF/eth0/10:1f:74:e3:50:5a
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x78a08d03)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0x78a08d03)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21 (xid=0x78a08d03)
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19 (xid=0x78a08d03)
...
(infinite, continue for ever)
```

Output of `ifconfig -a`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:1f:74:e3:50:5a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:298 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:298 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:23133 (23.1 KB)  TX bytes:23133 (23.1 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:de:2b:02:0b:da  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I have a `/etc/network/interfaces` file with the following content:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Ouptut of `cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

Output of `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

I'm also try static IP address but still have the problem. Please help me, I really do not have any other idea!

**UPDATE**

When I run `ifup eth0`, the `syslog` output is:

```
Jan 16 22:42:34 DEMON kernel: [16477.474586] r8169 0000:25:00.0 eth0: link down
Jan 16 22:42:34 DEMON avahi-daemon[1167]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.100.
Jan 16 22:42:34 DEMON avahi-daemon[1167]: New relevant interface eth0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jan 16 22:42:34 DEMON avahi-daemon[1167]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.100 on eth0.IPv4.
Jan 16 22:42:34 DEMON kernel: [16477.475316] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

So I tried Linux kernel version 14 and 18, but both have same problem.
Any idea?

**UPDATE 2**

I tried to use a static IP address, so I changed interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth1 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
provider dsl-provider

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Then `ifconfig -a`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:1f:74:e3:50:5a  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)


lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:34837 (34.8 KB)  TX bytes:34837 (34.8 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:37.254.165.125  P-t-P:37.254.128.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
          RX packets:7259 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8600 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:4900816 (4.9 MB)  TX bytes:1303955 (1.3 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:de:2b:02:0b:da  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Output of `sudo ethtool eth0`:

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  100baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 10Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Port: MII
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: d
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: no
```

**UPDATE 3**

My laptop has a problem, so I connect the laptop to a PC (rather than laptop to ADSL modem) and for now every thing is OK. But how can I connect laptop to ADSL modem?

This problem is related to Ubuntu because I checked several time on Windows 8 and I have no problem.

I reset ADSL modem router but still have the same problem.

**UPDATE 4**

I can detect Ethernet for once and everything was OK, but when I restart still have the same problem. There should be a command to fix this issue.

Comment: Hi it looks to me that your eth0 does not get an IP address. Are you sure that a DHCP server is running on that cable?
The second OS is it connected to the same networkcable or does it use wifi?

Comment: @Stefan I have a simple network, just is a ADSL modem. Yeah, I'm sure.

Comment: And the other question: "The second OS is it connected to the same network cable or does it use wifi?" ?

Comment: @MarcinKaminski connected to the same network cable. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: First thing to notice is that you don't have a physical link (ethtool's output). There's no point diagnosing anything above this layer before this works. Have you tried connecting this port to another machine's Ethernet port and seeing if you get a link?

Comment: @MarcinKaminski What The ..., My laptop have problem so I connect laptop to pc (rather than laptop to ADSL modem) for now every thing is OK. But how can I connect laptop to ADSL modem? Thanks again.

Comment: @MarcinKaminski I add update 2, do you have any other idea? Thank you so much.

Comment: OP: Did you ever solve this issue? I have the exact same problem here.

Comment: @UsAaR33 No, I think I have a hardware problem because recently I check with Windows xp and have the same problem in this OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the next steps and change BaseT by 10 100 or 1000 according to your network card:

Ldentify physical eth0 port: `ethtool --identify eth0`

Look config eth0: `ethtool eth0`

Force Ethernet to full duplex 100Tx: `ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off`

```
ifdown eth0 && ifup eth0
service network restart
```